# change angular material datePicker icon

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I wonder if it is possible to change the icon displayed using the datePicker of angular material.

This is the code from the angular material docs.

```html
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can add a mat-icon custom in mat-datepicker-toggle

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Select minimum date" disabled>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp">
  <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #dp disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: There is already a well working solution, please have a look at the accepted answer.

Comment: If you prefer a workaround no problem, it was just another solution. matDatepickerToggleIcon is a method from material. https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

Comment: This solution is much better than the accepted one especially since the >>> hack has been deprecated.

Comment: does this work with icons that are not in material? How do I insert an icon from src/assets?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by overriding the `background` property of `mat-datepicker-toggle` class. Add the path of an icon that you want from your `asset` folder.

Here's an example of replacing `calender` icon with an `alert.png` icon in `src > asset > img`:

```
>>> .mat-datepicker-toggle {
    background: url("../../assets/img/alert-circle-24.png") no-repeat !important;
}
```

html:

```
<md-input-container align="end">
   <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="datepicker"
                  [(ngModel)]="date">
   <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="datepicker"></button>
</md-input-container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can add your own image within

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix (click)="openCalendar()">
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>
        <img src={{imageSource}}>
    </mat-icon>
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
```

Comment: With MatIconRegistry is not necessary to do this, it's not so reusable, you can use https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIconRegistry you can check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xc5wkd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use svg for custom icon like this:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%; margin-top: 16px;">
    <mat-label style="font-size: 16px;">Date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="protocolIssueDate" formControlName="protocolIssueDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="protocolIssueDate">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M7 4L9 4V6L15 6V4L17 4V6L20 6V14H18V8L6 8L6 18H14V20H4L4 6H7V4Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.38"/>
                <path d="M10 12V10H8V12H10Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.38"/>
                <path d="M14 10L12 10V12L14 12V10Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.38"/>
                <path d="M10 16V14L8 14V16L10 16Z" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.38"/>
            </svg>
        </mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #protocolIssueDate startView="month" [startAt]="startProtocolIssueDate"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to do this (use Svg code inside <mat-icon> component), you can use https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIconRegistry you can check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xc5wkd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

The **matDatepickerToggleIcon** solution did not work for me, as I wanted a custom icon. I had to use CSS:

```
.mat-datetimepicker-toggle, .mat-datepicker-toggle {
    .mat-icon {
        background-image: url('../../assets/images/calendar.svg');
        background-position: 5px 2px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        svg {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Something that kept catching me out is, this needs to be in global styles, or at least, not scoped to some component x where x contains `<mat-form-field>` with `<mat-datepicker>`, for example (as it was in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xc5wkd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Custom Icon Outside of Material icons fonts**, this approach will be more **reusable** and clear to the developer.

```
<mat-form-field class="custom-mat-form-field" appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Choose a date 1</mat-label>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" />
<mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1">

  <!-- this icon is outside of Material icons font -->
  <mat-icon svgIcon="date_check_in" matDatepickerToggleIcon></mat-icon>
  <!-- you can check how do this in the link above -->
  
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
```

Result:
[image]

Angular 13